# Retrieving all datas from table? Swift, Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, backend

I'm new in Parse. I have leagues class, which has name. I want to take all names from table and show them in table view.

I wrote something like this:

```
   let query = PFQuery(className: "Leagues")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if( objects != nil && error == nil) {
            for i in objects! {
                let n = objects[i] as Leagues
            }
        }else if error != nil {
            print("Error is: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Error is:

> Type PSObject has no subscript members

What should I do for taking all names from table?

Comment: What is Parse? Can you explain better what is also PFObject? PFQuery?

Comment: Parse is backend server.

Comment: I know also Donaldduck as a backend server, can you explain better what do you speaking about? Some links, github repos, this question is totally incomprehensible

Comment: I have table(class) in "Parse" which name is "Leagues". I want to retrieve all objects from this table(class). How can i do this?

Comment: What is parse? What is PFObject? What is PFQuery? Is this https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide ? So please , report links or some help in your question thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you are in right link.

Comment: I know, but some people who read this question could also might not even know what you mean, and vote this question to close it.

Comment: Use the PF table view controller...

Comment: Do you get the error in your print statement or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that your "i" in your for loop is actually the  reference to the PFObject not the PFObject Array. 
So the compiler is giving you correct information when it says that the individual PFObject does not have any Subscript members.

Try this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Leagues")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if( objects != nil && error == nil) {
            for i in objects! {
                let n = i as Leagues // Assuming your PFObject is a list of Leagues 
            }
        }else if error != nil {
            print("Error is: \(error)")
        }
    }
```